# Timeseries extraction based on specific data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataframe containg profitability information of millions of clients. For every client, there are several rows containg the probitability of every month for the last years (example df above).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'client' :  ['john', 'john','john','john','john','john','john','john','john','john','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo','rambo'],
    'profit' : [100, 200,200,150,300,0,50,1513,51,5465,54645,54654,4875,7875,5132,202,512,10,242,2131],
    'date' : [date(2022,1,1),date(2022,2,1),date(2022,3,1),date(2022,4,1),date(2022,5,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,7,1),date(2022,8,1),date(2022,9,1),date(2022,10,1),date(2023,1,1),date(2023,2,1),date(2023,3,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,5,1),date(2023,6,1),date(2023,7,1),date(2023,8,1),date(2023,9,1),date(2023,10,1)],
    'new_produt_start_date' : [date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2022,6,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1),date(2023,4,1)]})
```

[image: Example output]

For every client there is a specific information that details since when such client started to use a target product.

what I want is to analyse if starting using the new product was affecting the client probitability (looking for client profitability some months before new product up to some months after the new product).

I am really strugling how to adapt such information so I could see somenthing like this:

| client | start_date | proft_2months_before | proft_1months_before | proft_1months_after | proft_2months_after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2023/01 | 100 | 120 | 500 | 400 |

Comment: Can you provide a row with an exact result, please?

Comment: I do not understand the relationship between your raw data and your desired output. We need you to explain this to us so that we can give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is what you are looking for.

**Option 1**

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['new_produt_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_produt_start_date'])
for i in range(1, 3):
    df[f'profit_{i}months_before'] = df.apply(lambda row:
                            df[(row['client'] == df['client']) &
                               (df['date'] >= row['new_produt_start_date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=i)) &
                                (df['date'] < row['new_produt_start_date'])]['profit'].sum(), axis=1)
    df[f'profit_{i}months_after'] = df.apply(lambda row:
                             df[(row['client'] == df['client']) &
                                (df['date'] <= row['new_produt_start_date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=i)) &
                                 (df['date'] > row['new_produt_start_date'])]['profit'].sum(), axis=1)
print(df.drop(columns=['profit'])
      .groupby(['client', 'new_produt_start_date'])
      .mean(numeric_only=True))
```

```
                              profit_1months_before  profit_1months_after  profit_2months_before  profit_2months_after
client new_produt_start_date
john   2022-06-01                            300.0                 50.0                 450.0               1563.0
rambo  2023-04-01                           4875.0               5132.0               59529.0               5334.0
```

---

**Option 2**

A more straightforward approach:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['new_produt_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_produt_start_date'])

mask_1m_before = (df['date'] >= df['new_produt_start_date'] -
                  pd.DateOffset(months=1)) & (df['date'] < df['new_produt_start_date'])
mask_1m_after = (df['date'] <= df['new_produt_start_date'] +
                 pd.DateOffset(months=1)) & (df['date'] > df['new_produt_start_date'])
mask_2m_before = (df['date'] >= df['new_produt_start_date'] -
                  pd.DateOffset(months=2)) & (df['date'] < df['new_produt_start_date'])
mask_2m_after = (df['date'] <= df['new_produt_start_date'] +
                 pd.DateOffset(months=2)) & (df['date'] > df['new_produt_start_date'])

df['profit_1m_before'] = df[mask_1m_before]['profit']
df['profit_1m_after'] = df[mask_1m_after]['profit']
df['profit_2m_before'] = df[mask_2m_before]['profit']
df['profit_2m_after'] = df[mask_2m_after]['profit']

mask_all =  (df['profit_1m_before'].notnull() |
            df['profit_1m_after'].notnull() |
            df['profit_2m_before'].notnull() |
             df['profit_2m_after'].notnull())

print(df[mask_all]
      .drop(columns=['profit'])
      .groupby(['client', 'new_produt_start_date'])
      .sum(numeric_only=True))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test it later. I could do it using apply but it takes too much time. Your second method seems to be more efficient.

Comment: Option 2 updated for better efficiency using a single `groupby/agg` and `mask_all` to reduce rows. This should improve performance.

Comment: Your solution was excellent! I am studding it so I can really understand what you did!